# Z-index issue for lightning-button-menu in lightning-modal

Tags: css, lightning-modal

[image: Menu appears behind modal-footer]

This is my issue, when using `<lightning-modal>`. I've read several posts here about z-index issues, but I haven't found any that address the `<lightning-modal>` situation, which I suspect has built in z-index parameters to pop it to the front.

I tried applying a z-index (and position: relative) css class to the menu, but it did nothing. This next image is a similar modal I created prior to `<lightning-modal>` just using a regular lwc. This is how the menu should appear relative to the footer.

[image: Desired appearance, vis-a-vis menu and footer]

Css is not my strong suit, so any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: A copy paste example so we don't have to build the entire thing ourselves would be appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar issue... Could you maybe help? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/419818/lightning-datatables-inline-edit-form-expanding-too-much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that z-index *does work*, but I just wasn't thinking big enough. I found this [info about slds z-index](https://summer-20.lightningdesignsystem.com/design-tokens/#category-z-index) that specifies that `lightning-modal` is z-index 9000. I set my z-index for the `lightning-button-menu` to 9100 and it works!

```
.merge-menu{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9100;
}
```

It does not work with `position:relative`, so with `position:absolute` I had to apply some css to the surrounding elements, but those were easy tweaks.

Here's the result:
[image: lightning-modal with z-index css on lightning-button-menu]