# Lightning Datatable's Inline Edit form expanding too much

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, lightning-datatable, inline-editing

I have a lightning-datatable inside a custom modal form component. The lightning-datatable is inside its own component that has other elements.

Upon clicking on a editable field, the inline edit is expanding too much. It also goes outside the modal form itself.

Any way to resize it or keep it inside that element?

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <div>
        <h1 slot="title" class='picklistStyle'>
            {multiselectPicklistTitle}
        </h1>
        <!-- Below code will show dropdown picklist -->
        <template if:true={showDropdown}>
            <div class="slds-box_border multiselectDropDownStyle">
                <ul class="dropdown-list slds-dropdown_length-7 slds-p-left_medium">
                    <template for:each={filteredResults} for:item="profile">
                        <li key={profile.Id} class="dropdown-item">
                            <lightning-input type="checkbox" checked={profile.isChecked} label={profile.Name}
                                value={profile.Id} onchange={handleSelection}>
                            </lightning-input>
                        </li>
                    </template>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </template>
        
        <template if:false={showDropdown}>
            <p>{emptyPicklistValuesMessage}</p>
        </template>
    </div>
    <div onclick={catchClick} class="datatable-container" id="table">
        <lightning-datatable
        key-field="id"
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        suppress-bottom-bar
        oncellchange={handleCellChange}
        hide-checkbox-column="true"
        errors={errors}
        draft-values={draftedValues}>
    </lightning-datatable>
</div>
</lightning-card>
```

The above code is a child component of a parent custom modal component.
The custom modal I used is a modified version of this https://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/modal-popup-lightning-web-component-lwc/

[image]

Comment: Share your LWC markup.

Comment: @PatMcClellan__c I edited the question.